# Package with subpackage; How to do local (editable) pip-install?

Tags: pip, packaging

I apparently can't wrap my head around packaging in Python so I have to pester someone with my incompetence.

I have the following directory structure:

```
package/main.py

package/helpers/helper1.py
package/helpers/helper2.py

package/tests/specialtests1/test_something.py
```

`main.py` uses `helpers` without troubles, I can e.g. do `from helpers.helper1 import some_function`. But when I use functionality from `helpers` in `test_something.py` and I run pytest from `package/` I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`.

I know that this is an old problem, but I still can't solve this. I don't want to modify my path and such kludges, I just want to be able to do a local (editable) pip-install for `main.py` and `helpers` so that both are available package-wide. I'd prefer a solution with `pyproject.toml`.

Is this really so hard to do in Python or am I missing something?